# Argument after * must be an inter able, not float

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a hard time diagnosing this problem. I figured it was an issue with the location of the `*`, but I didn't have any luck. Then I thought it was the issue with the parentheses of my call function, but also no luck.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def Psat(T,*args):
    '''
    Calculate the saturation pressure of a component.
    '''
    return 10**(args[0] - args[1]/(T + args[2]))

def dew_pt(T,*args):
    '''
    This will calculate the dew point temperature of a binary system.
    '''
    return (y*P)/Psat(T,*args[0]) + ((1-y)*P)/Psat(T,*args[1]) - 1

def bubble_pt(T,*args):
    '''
    This will calculate the bubble point temperature of a binary system.
    '''
    return (x*Psat(T,*args[0]))/P + (1-x)*Psat(T,*args[1])/P - 1

def plot(dew,bubble):
    '''
    Plotting the dew point and bubble point on a graph.
    '''
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(60,60))
    plt.plot(x,dew, 'r-',label = 'Dew Point')
    plt.plot(x,bubble, 'b-', label = 'Bubble Point')
    plt.legend(loc = 'best')
    plt.xlabel('Composition')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature $^\circ$C')
    plt.show()
    return fig

#Constants
P = 760 #Units: mmHg
liquid_comp = np.linspace(0,1,101)
vap_comp = np.linspace(0,1,101)

#Antoine Constants A, B, C
Ben_Con = (6.91, 1211, 221)
Tol_Con = (6.95, 1344, 219)

dew = []
for y in vap_comp:
    ans = fsolve(dew_pt,25,*(Ben_Con,Tol_Con))
    dew.append(ans)
```

The error is given below

```
  File "C:\Users\ayubi\Documents\Python Files\Chemical Engineering Files\Txy.py", line 22, in dew_pt
    return (y*P)/Psat(T,*args[0]) + ((1-y)*P)/Psat(T,*args[1]) - 1

TypeError: Psat() argument after * must be an iterable, not float
```

I am sure it is an easy fix, I just can't find the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Psat(T,*args[0])`?

Comment: Pass in the tuple in either variable `Ben_Con` or `Tol_Con`

Comment: Double check `fsolve` docs; the `args=()` argument should be a tuple, not an expanded one.  So `*(Ben_Con,Tol_Con)` is wrong.    Within `dew_pt` print the `args` variable, so you have a clear idea of what `fsolve` is passing to it.  The `*args[0]` does look suspicious, though if args is sufficiently nested it might work.  But you are doing this through several layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out! Yay!

Props to @hpaulj for the lead.

The problem was essentially the calling of the fsolve function

I was suppose to call the fsolve function as

```
ans = fsolve(dew_pt, 25, args = (Ben_Con, Tol_Con)
```

Not

```
ans = fsolve(dew_pt, 25, (Ben_Con, Tol_Con))
```

This is because according to the documentation of `fsolve` there are several parameters that pass as a tuple, and I just need to specify which tuple I am specifying what.

I knew it was an easy fix, (:

Thanks for y'all help!

Comment: Yes, the original code `ans = fsolve(dew_pt,25,*(Ben_Con,Tol_Con))` is equivalent to `ans = fsolve(dew_pt,25,Ben_Con, Tol_Con)`. So it passes `Ben_Con` and `Tol_Con` as separate parameters to `fsolve`. Instead, you want to group them as the parameters to the function you are trying to solve as you found.

Comment: Just to emphasize, the difference is NOT `args = `. Instead, it is the spurious `*` in the call to `fsolve()`.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly the problem. You are using `*` on a float `args[0]` when you can only use this on an iterable (such as a list or tuple).

Look at `Psat()`:

```
def Psat(T,*args):
    '''
    Calculate the saturation pressure of a component.
    '''
    return 10**(args[0] - args[1]/(T + args[2]))
```

This shows that we are using `args` as a list. `args` is declared as `*args`, meaning that it is gathering the rest of the arguments to the function into a list.

This means that when you call `Psat()`, you need to pass it 4 total parameters:

```
Psat(T, x, y, z)
```

A common shortcut is to "splat" an iterable as the parameters. If you have a list with the parameters, then you can do

```
Psat(T, *args)
```

Notice there is no index here. You just pass all of the values from `args` to `Psat`.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense? What I am trying to do is when I call `dew_pt` function, I am passing a tuple within a tuple, more specifically, `Ben_Con` and `Tol_Con.` When that tuple is pass through, it breaks down to its values to the function `Psat.`

Comment: @uBoscuBo I see that my proposed solution is too simplistic. The general idea is correct, though. You need to pass parameters in such a way that `*` applies to a tuple instead of a single float. I suggest you keep working on it to see what you can figure out on your own. I will have time to look at this in more detail later this afternoon.

Comment: @uBoscuBo Comments are not intended for showing code snippets. Fell free to edit your original question with an addendum. I think you should keep your current example, though, since it illustrates the complexities of what you are doing.